# Can't access webdav server after password change in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, nautilus, webdav

I have been accessing a webdav server through `nautilus` without issue until yesterday. I changed my password, and now I get an error message

```
Oops! Something went wrong.
Unhandled error message: HTTP Error: Unauthorized.
```

I have rebooted twice, but it seems I can no longer access the server. I can access it through a browser, though, so I'm still authorized. I have tried both

```
davs://server/dav
davs://user@server/dav
```

and with both I get the error message. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to passwords and keys on your application window. Select the network and change the password. I had the same problem and got it fixed just now :)